# If else statement based on array/dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I want to categorizing data by city based on string in a column in dataframe. Firstly, I've tried to create the if-else statement but the code become so long. So, So, i plan to create the if-else statement based on array in which the query read if there is same data between data in dataframe and array, before categorizing the data.

Sample data:

```
**full**
london
menchester united 
i live in mench
lndon
lndn is huge
chester
scotland
scot
menches
manchaster
```

My code is

```
import pandas as pd

    data = pd.read_excel (r'/c:/Documents/data.xlsx')
    
    def func(a):
        london = ['london','lo','ldn','lnn','lndon','lon','ld','ndn']
        manchester = ['hester','ester','mencstr']
    
        if str(london) in a.lower():
            return "london"
        elif str(manchester) in a.lower():
            return "manchester"
        else:
            return "others"
    
    data["city"] = data["full"].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Initial if-else statement code:

```
          if "london" in a.lower():
                return "london"
          elif "lond" in a.lower():
                return "london"
          elif "lndn" in a.lower():
                return "london"
            elif "menchester" in a.lower():
                return "manchester"
            elif "hester" in a.lower():
                return "manchester"
            elif "mnhester" in a.lower():
                return "manchester"
            else:
                return "others"
```

This code is definitely wrong. but im not sure how to change it so that I dont have to create a long if-else statement, but instead that if-else statement will compare the data from array/dictionary.
Note: data in code is just an example, the real data is big.

Comment: You have your checks backwards... `if a.lower() in london` will check if the lowered string is in the list. You should also store the possible lists of names outside of the function

Comment: Ultimately, I don't see  a way around "writing a long if-else" that lists out all possible "names"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'/c:/Documents/data.xlsx')

def func(a):

    # creating dict like {"lnn":"london","ld":"london"}
    london_dict = {k:"london" for k in ['london','lo','ldn','lnn','lndon','lon','ld','ndn']}
    menchester_dict = {k:"menchester" for k in ['hester','ester','mencstr']}

    # Merging all the dicts
    city_dict = {**london_dict ,**menchester_dict }

    if a.lower() in city_dict.keys():
        return city_dict[a.lower()]
    else:
        return "others"

data["city"] = data["full"].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Comment: Although easier, it will be slower because of the `.apply`. @swm

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary for your data and use `pandas.Series.str.contains` to check if it exists. Use `numpy.where` to conditionally replace. Note that, `contains` method uses regex to search in the column

```
import numpy as np

data = {
    'london': ['london','lo','ldn','lnn','lndon','lon','ld','ndn'],
    'manchester': ['hester','ester','mencstr']
}

for city, alts in data.items():
    df['full'] = np.where(df.full.str.contains('|'.join(alts)), city, df['full'])
```

OR, Another more efficient one-liner would be to use `replace`

```
df.full.replace({'|'.join(d): c for c, d in data.items()})
```

Output

```
         full
0      london
1  manchester
2       mench
3      london
4      london
5  manchester
6    scotland
7        scot
8     menches
9  manchaster
```